# C#: What does writing data as a block? Data Queue scrambled [Redux]

Tags: c#

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478616/why-in-c-is-queue-scrambling-the-data-in-its-elements), I asked about using queue's and threads in C#.  I found that locking around the code that writes data to file resolved my issue.  One of the [ansewerers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20029/zach-scrivena), thought that the problem was that the data was being written as a ["block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478616/why-in-c-is-queue-scrambling-the-data-in-its-elements#478630).

Is this because arrays are reference objects?  To ask it in another way

```
int[] a = {1, 2 ,3, 4};
int[] b = int[4];
b=a;
a[1]=5;
```

Does b[1]=1 still? I would have thought so? So, what does Zach mean by writing data "as a block"?

Thanks

Azim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b[1] no longer exists, and will be garbage collected.

You create array a.

You create array b.

when you say b=a you throw away the reference to array b.

b[1] and a[1] are now pointing at the same array.

Comment: thanks for your answer. anyway, my brain is tired. going to close question until I can reformulate it better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a copy of *a* I would need to write

```
b=(int[])a.Clone();
```

Instead of

```
b=a;
```

because in C# arrays are reference types.